# Charger noise "coil whine"

Tags: transformer, charger

I have a charger that make high pitch noise only when I disconnect the device from the charger.

The charger is "switched-mode power supply"

**Input:** 100-240V AC 150 mA 50-60Hz
**Output:** 5V DC 850 mA

- I have tried everything that I know, I tried to re-solder pins and
  some components on the main board.
- I tried to glue the transformer and the capacitor and other components
  with silicon.

I checked if the output or the input signal not smooth! but everything work perfectly and the output is stable!

I'm not sure from where exactly this high pitch come from! from the transformer or a capacitor.

NOTE: The charger make high pitch noise even if I unplug it from the wall! for around 35 second and the noise is so high even old people can hear it from other room!
[image]

Is there any way to solve that!

Comment: Put it in a small sound proof box?

Comment: ..oh come on! :(

Comment: Sounds very normal to me. You are hearing piezo-electrical and/or mechanical noise due to Lentz law in the transformer and possibly capacitors as you say due to skip mode for energy saving in your charger.

Comment: I agree, this high pitched whine is perfectly normal and is likely due to either the piezo-electric noise as winny mentioned, or it is simply one of the switching coils. When the charger is loaded (i.e. the device is connected to it) these oscillations are damped, but when disconnected they are not. If it's bothering you, @Andyaka 's suggestion is probably the way to go (no joke!)

Comment: Well, it's not a very green solution but you could try experimenting with a minimum load i.e. if you can draw some small amount of current from the charger to stop the noise then do that - try a few resistors that represent a light load and see if the noise goes away then, when you unplug the "device" plug the charger into a socket soldered to a resistor (that might consume a couple of hundred milli watts). What's the picture BTW and its relevance to the question?

Comment: okay I know it's normal for a capacitor or a transformer to make a noise! but this noise is crazy even old people can hear it from other room! I was thinking in the same solution @Andyaka becuse it's only make sound when there is no loud on the charger, maybe a small LED will solve this, I will look into that and i will back..

Comment: Ferrite is ceramic with iron particles. Cheap or cracked ferrite has poor binder material and very piezo like and noisy.  IF there is a way to adjust the frequency of SMPS with a pot or tuning cap so that it is > 20kHz . Consult with seller if you don't know how to fix. If your load is switching at this frequency then that is another cause. like stepper motors or no load is another cause.

Comment: If you are putting glue in the supply, Throw it in the garbage and buy a name brand power supply. You have compromised the isolation of the supply.

Comment: "Is there any way to solve that" - yes, buy a new one which is more quiet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you disconnect a load from a switching power supply, there is no  or very little current. Most switching power supplies work on principle of PWM - pulse-width modulation of power pulses that are essentially "filtered" by a power inductor and output capacitor. The pulses are normally coming at high switching rate, 200 kHz, 400 kHz, up to 2+ MHz, well above the audio range. So, if there are any piezo-electric effects in the inductor, people can't hear this.

However, this schema starts failing to work at low loads. If the load current goes low, the pulse width gets narrower and narrower, up to extinction. Some switchers transition into a linear mode when this happens, some cheap one start skipping pulses, so the effective repetition rate enters the audible frequency diapason, and all electro-mechanical and/or piezo-electrical effects start to annoy you.

When you unplug your charger from the wall, the input capacitor is still charged up, and with no load it takes about 30 second to discharge. That's why you still hear the pitch.

If this is bothering you, you need to get a better designed charger.

Comment: Awesome answer, it's sony charger! the original one, I just added a resistor to make loud on the charger when there is nothing to charge, resistor between GND and 5V 330ohm, draws around 0.01A and works perfectly, no more sounds, thanks

Comment: @narzan, glad to hear this. If it is Sony, then it must be some part defect, loose coil, or cracked/loose ferrite core, or something, although I had some negative encounters with contemporary Sony Engineering as well...

Comment: I re-solder everything to be sure nothing loose, 330ohm resistor solve everything, I will record the heat at night to be sure nothing gonna go wrong.

Comment: @narzan, the defect is likely inside either the main transformer, or in other power inductor, so re-soldering might not help.

Comment: I tried to glue the transformer with silicone but the pitch doesn't change for that it's for sure not from transformer, seems like bad cap maybe, anyway a resistor works perfect for me, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @narzan if adapter's age is more than 2-3 years there may be a faulty electrolytic cap responsible for that noise.